# Calling one appengine project from another: slow UrlFetchService

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two appengine projects A and B, and I need to call an api exposed by B from A. The serverside latency of the api request (on B) is about 300 ms. I am using `urllib/urllib2` in python on A which seems to be using url fetch service and is taking about 3 seconds to finish the request.

My question is, since this is a call from appengine to appengine, is there a way to make this faster? If it were allowed to connect directly without url-fetch-service it should have been much faster.

Comment: Is it always taking that long? First request might take time in case B instance is down. I have same requirement, they are pretty fast.

Comment: Tried with multiple calls, some of them did come faster 400 - 600 ms range - much more manageable, but it does not seem to be related to the instance B being up - that has always been up. I am not sure what is making some of these requests fast while most of them are slow. The serveside latency for all of them is in the same range 150 ms - 300 ms. Any insights here?

Comment: @Siva, are you using urllib/urllib2?

Comment: No. I had timeouts for initial requests, but its a java application. Your problem might be different.

Comment: Using urlfetch directly, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_a_request_to_another_app_engine_app), may be faster.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is urlfetch and not just the cost of processing performed by B?  If B is doing a few requests to the datastore then that could easily get you in the 600ms range.

Comment: The problem is indeed in urlfetch - I have looked at traces from A and stats/logs from B. They all imply that the time is being spent in urlfetch. There is around 2 second delay between start of url-fetch on A and the time B receives the call, though there are times when this is pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take advantage of the fact that both your apps run on GAE you should make them separate services/modules inside the same app. Only then GAE would know they're "friendlies" and could shortcut a lot of the egress and ingress request processing.

Otherwise GAE has no clue that the packet sent by one app is destined to another GAE app. It *could* determine that, but by making additional processing, which would slow down the egress side for all apps - not worthy IMHO for the very tiny percentage of the apps that could benefit from such processing.

Same on the ingress side - there is a lot of routing and security processing in the GAE infra that needs to be done before the request even reaches the app. Some of it would need to be done even if the request comes from GAE - it could be from a malicious app - again the extra processing required to determine if shortcuts could be made for a few apps would slow down the ingress side for all apps.

If you want, that'd be similar with the connecting service in an airport: you can literally spend just seconds from the arriving gate 61 to the departing gate 62 - if you have connected flights. Otherwise you'd have to exit the secured zone and go again through checkin and the security checks. Which can take a varying amount of time, depending on a lot more than just the distance between the gates.